# ¿Cómo comparar fechas de horas de entrada y salida con un horario ya establecido?

Tags: c#

Tengo que realizar un sistema de control de registro de entradas y salidas de personal para una institución. El sistema debe permitir registrar hora de entrada y salida de cada empleado y a partir de ahí hacer una comparación con el horario ya establecido de dicho empleado para que en una tabla de la base de datos guarde las incidencias (retardo, jornada incompleta, etc) de dicho empleado.

¿Qué tipo de dato deben de tener mi tabla de horarios en la que voy a ingresar los horarios de cada empleado y que tipo de dato debe tener mi tabla de entradas y salidas para poder hacer la comparación con los horarios y así generar las incidencias?

Comment: ¿Preguntas tipos de datos a nivel de base de datos? si es así, ¿con qué base de datos trabajas?

Comment: SQL Server, lo que pasa es que ya tengo mis tablas pero tengo duda en que tipo de dato usar para poder hacer la comparacion de horario contra hora de entrada y salida que es en tiempo real es decir estos los tomara de la computadora y el horario ya esta definido para cada empleado.

Comment: c# no tiene un tipo especializado en manejar _horas_, puedes utilizar un `DateTime` e ignorar la parte de fecha.

Answer (score 0):

Las columnas en tu tabla deben de tener tipo de dato DATETIME y puedes hacer el cálculo con DATEDIFF para el tipo de unidades que requieras (días, horas, minutos, etc)

```
DECLARE @Date1 DATETIME
DECLARE @Date2 DATETIME

SET @Date1 = '2019-05-20 12:33:03.257'
SET @Date2 = '2019-05-21 22:33:03.257'

SELECT DATEDIFF(dd, @Date1, @Date2)
SELECT DATEDIFF(hh, @Date1, @Date2)
```

Ahora, si es en C#; el tipo de dato a usar es DateTime y la comparación la haces con una operación matematica pero que te regresa un tipo de dato TimeSpan:

```
DateTime start = new DateTime(2019, 5, 20, 12, 33, 3);
DateTime end = new DateTime(2019, 5, 21, 22, 33, 3);

TimeSpan difference = end - start;

Console.WriteLine("Difference in days: " + difference.Days); // 1 (solo compara días)
Console.WriteLine("Difference in days: " + difference.TotalDays); // 1.41666666666667 (compara la fecha completa)
Console.WriteLine("Difference in hours: " + difference.Hours); // 10 (solo compara horas)
Console.WriteLine("Difference in hours: " + difference.TotalHours); // 34 (compara la fecha completa; 1 días + 10 horas)
```

Comment: Dices que las columnas sean de tipo DateTime y esto esta bien en mi tabla de entradas y salidas, pero en la de horarios no estoy muy seguro, es decir, cada empleado tiene una hora de entrada y salida diferente cada día  y ya son dias definidos en decir todos los lunes entra a una una hora y sale a otra y asi con los demas dias, si pongo el campo dias de tipo DateTime en este tendría que poner una fecha ya definida, es decir, lunes 26 de junio del 2019 y solo estaría poniendo el horario para ese día no para todos los lunes, en la hora no hay problema va de tipo time pero en el dia si.

Comment: Interesante tu requerimiento, no lo había necesitado como tal. Tal vez esta referencia te sirva: https://docs.microsoft.com/es-mx/sql/t-sql/data-types/time-transact-sql

Comment: Gracias, estaré revisando.